# Does the foreach the same as classic for?

Tags: c#, foreach, enumeration, ilist

Regarding the collections implementing `this[int]` and **assuming the collection won't change during the enumeration**, does the `foreach (var item in list)` loop produce the same sequence as `for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)` anytime?

This means, when I need the ascending order by index, could I use `foreach` or is just simply safer to use `for`? Or it just depends on the curren collection implementation and migh vary or change in time?

Comment: Normally `foreach` is based on the `GetEnumerator` method (except sometimes on arrays).

Comment: if you need to know the index, use `for` otherwise, its your choice

Comment: Unless there's a performance reason, `foreach` is more concise and less likely to contain silly bugs over `for` followed by an index based lookup. I'd prefer it almost every time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman `++i` is pretty common as well, especially with C++ programmers. It can yield better performance if `i` is a complex type.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Do you have any reference to that fact? (I'm curious as to how it could be)

Comment: I `++i` because logically, it's one less op, although the compiler/jitter probably takes care of it for you.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929586/what-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach).

Comment: @Sayse `i++` modifies the variable but returns the original value. So it needs to create a copy. If that copy cannot be optimized out, it decreases performance. For integers any decent compiler will optimize it, but in C++ it's common to use more complex iterators where the compiler might not be able to do that. In C# it should never matter, since you can't overload `i++` or `++i` directly, you only overload a shared increment function.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Sayse it's been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) as well.

Comment: @Ognyan Dimitrov thanks, I missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, but strictly spoken: no. It really depends on the implementation.

Usually with `for` you would use the `this` indexer properties. `foreach` uses `GetEnumerator()` to get the enumerator that iterates over the collection. Depending on the implementation the enumerator might yield another result than the `for`.

The implied logic of a list is that is has a specific order, and when implementing `IList` you may state is it save to assume that the order of both the indexer properties as the enumerator are the same.

Comment: I'd argue that the indexer and enumeration returning different sequences violates the implied contract of `IList<T>` (even if microsoft might not have bothered to specify that contract explicitly)

Comment: I didn't mention `IList<T>`, nor did OP. For `IList<T>` and arrays I would agree the sequence would be the same.

Comment: The question is tagged with [ilist]

Comment: Please be more specific (yes to which question?) Because the answer is really **no**, then **yes**: No, there is no indexer involved, and [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) nowhere uses an index, but yes you can *normally* count on things being iterated in order.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    // do things
}
```

translates to

```
var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
   var item = enumerator.Current;
   // do things
}
```

So as you can see, it's not using the indexor `list[i]` in the general case.
For most collections types, however, the semantics is the same.

**edit**

There are `IList<T>` implementations where the enumerator IList<T> as a linked list, it's very unlikely you will use the indexor in your enumerator implementation, as it would be very inefficient.
As a rule of thumb, using `foreach` ensure you use the most efficient algorithm for the class at hand, as it is the one chosen by the class' Creator. In the worst case, you will just suffer a small indirection overhead that is very unlikely to be noticeable.

**edit 2 after nos's comment**

There is a case where the semantics of the two constructs varies widly: the collection modification.

While using a simple `for` loop, nothing particular will happen if you change the collection while iterating through it. The program will behave as if it assumed you know what you're doing. This could result in some values iterated over more than once or other skipped, but no exception as long as you're not accessing outside of the range of the indexor (which would require a multithreaded program ot happen).

While using a `foreach`loop; if you modify the collection while iterating through it, you enter undefined behavior. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx) tells us

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and its behavior is undefined.
>   In that case, expect most of C# built-in types to throw an `InvalidOperationException`, but everything can happen in a custom implementation, from missed values to repeated values , including infinite loops...

Comment: If the `IList<T>` in question is the `List<T>` provided by the framework then the indexer is used internally, but this isn't specific to `IList<T>`, it just happens to be the way it is implemented.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth : so very true. But as I pointed out in my answer, it's not generally the case. For instance, you can easily create a linked list that implements `IList<T>`. In that case, the enumerator is very unlikely to use the indexor internally (as the indexor in a linked list is not very efficient).

Comment: OP did not mention any `IList`, just a variable called `list` that is a collection implementing `this[int]`.

Comment: @Gutblender : He put IList in the tags, so I assume that's what he had in mind.

Comment: Of particular interest is the case where you modify the collection you're iterating over, which would behave very differently using `foreach` vs `for`

Comment: @nos : very important comment. I'm adding it to my answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that this would be the case. The code paths can be completely separate. Of course collections like List will produce the same result but you can write data structures (even useful ones) that do not.

The indexer is just a property with additional index argument. You can return a random value if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

One important think you should have in mind, as a difference between the 2 is that inside foreach you can/t make any changes to the enumarared objects.
If you wish to alter (basicaly delete) objects from the enumeration you must use a for loop