# Difference between forEach and for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am wondering: Is there any significant difference between `forEach` and `for` loop in JavaScript.

Consider this example:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];

myArray.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(myArray[i]);
}
```

Here is part of my research:

1. **Performance**: According to [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/foreach-and-for) : forEach is little slower than for loop.
2. **Usability**: There is no way we can break/return from the callback in case of forEach loop.

For example: You want to find out if a number is prime or not. I think using for loop is much more easier than using forEach loop to do this.

3. **Readability:** Using for loop makes code more readable than having forEach in code.
4. **Browser compatibility**: forEach is Not supported in IE < 9 So that introduces some shim in our code.

My questions are:

1. What are the advantages of forEach over for loop ?
2. In what scenarios, forEach is more preferable.
3. Why did even it come into JavaScript ? Why was it needed at all ?

Comment: Well technically you can break out of a for each by throwing an error.... 1) Opinion 2) Opinion 3) Opinion.

Comment: @Sirko—I think you mean `[1,2,,3,4]`. The array in your comment has five members, both *for* and *forEach* will visit all five. However, if one (or more) members don't exist (a so called "sparse" array) then *forEach* will not visit the missing members.

Comment: @RobG Right. Can't correct now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between for and foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929586/what-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach)

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the suggestion of throw and catch....But it is just a workaround...I would still go by for loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a method on the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) prototype. It iterates through each element of an array and passes it to a callback function.

So basically, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a shorthand method for the use-case *"pass each element of an `array` to a `function`"*. Here is a common example where I think [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is quite useful, compared to a `for` loop:

```
// shortcut for document.querySelectorAll
function $$(expr, con) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

// hide an element
function hide(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
}

// hide all divs via forEach
$$('div').forEach(hide); 

// hide all divs via for
for (var divs = $$('div'), i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    hide(divs[i])
}
```

As you can see, the readability of the forEach statement is improved compared to a `for` loop.

On the other hand, a `for` statement is more flexible: it does not necessarily involve an array. The performance of a normal `for` loop is slightly better, because there is no function call for each element involved. Despite of this, it is recommended to avoid `for` loops when it can be written as a `forEach` statement.

Comment: You definitely made a great point in favour of forEach..Accepted.

Comment: but where is the difference? you have given info only to forEach

Comment: @Silver Bullet thank you, I revised my answer to provide more info to `for` and clarify the difference.

Answer (score 20):

In a `forEach` loop you don't control the way you iterate over the array. The classic `for` loop allows you to choose the iteration algorithm as you want (`i++`; `i--`; `i+=2*i`, etc).

However, a `forEach` loop is much easier to use - you don't need to mess with all the `i` counting, finding the `array[i]` object -- JS does it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the nice point..+1. It is really good point about loops that you can manipulate loop index according to your situation. For example: Printing even numbers.

Answer (score 8):

```
>> sparseArray = [1, 2, , 4];

>> sparseArray.forEach(console.log, console);
1 0 [1, 2, 3: 4] 
2 1 [1, 2, 3: 4] 
4 3 [1, 2, 3: 4] 

>> for(var i = 0; i < sparseArray.length; ++i) { console.log(sparseArray[i]) };
1
2
undefined
4
```

`forEach` is a recent addition to make expressive list-comprehension style possible in javascript. Here you can see that `forEach` *skips elements that were never set*, but the best you can do with a `for` loop is to check for `undefined` or `null`, both of which can be set as values and picked up by `forEach`. Unless you expect missing values, `forEach` is equivalent to `for` loops, but note that you cannot stop early, for which you need `every`.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, according to the below article, and research, it seems that the main differences are:

**For Loop**

1. It's one of the original ways of iterating over arrays
2. It's faster
3. You could `break` out of it using this keyword
4. In my opinion its mainly used for calculations with integers (numbers)
5. The parameters are `(iterator, counter, incrementor)`

**ForEach Loop**

1. It's a newer way with less code to iterate over arrays
2. Easier to read
3. Lets you keep variable within the scope
4. Lower chance of accidental errors with the `i <= >= etc.....`
5. The parameters are `(iterator, Index of item, entire array)`

https://alligator.io/js/foreach-vs-for-loops/

Answer (score 1):

**forEach**

1. forEach is a method on the Array prototype.
2. It is easy to use
3. It contains a callback function and each element from array is passed to callback function
4. Because of callback, **You can not use await with forEach** ,it will lead to different output than expected.
5. Because of callback function it is slower than for loop
6. Because of callback you can not use break

**For loop**

1. In for loop you need an index, condition and increment/decrement of index variable
2. It is faster than foreach
3. You can use break
4. **It works with await**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a difference between forEach and for loop in JavaScript.

Performance wise, I prefer the for loop over the forEach loop.
This is just one of some issues I have come across with the forEach loop.

```
let abc = [1,2,3] 

abc.forEach((e) => { 
   delete e; 
}) 

console.log(abc)  //Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]

for (let i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) { 
   delete abc[i]; 
} 

console.log(abc)  //Array(3) [ <3 empty slots> ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from flexibility, one main reason why I would use the `for` loop is if I needed to `break` out of a loop early.

In the below sample code if you wanted to only return a certain `value` in your array, you could use an `if` statement to check if your criteria matchs, and then break out from the loop. The `forEach` method would iterate over each food, which could lead to performance issues.

```
//Assume that foodArray has been declared
for (let i = 0; i < foodArray.length; i++) {
  if (foodArray[i].name === 'Pizza') {
    console.log('PIZZA EXISTS');
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a method on `Array` prototype which intakes a function expression that it executes on each iteration and within this function, the current iterated item of the Array is passed as the first argument.

**ForEach structure:**

```js
// Arrow function
forEach((element) => { /* … */ })
forEach((element, index) => { /* … */ })
forEach((element, index, array) => { /* … */ })
```

On the other hand, A `for` loop is a construct inherent to JavaScript language itself. `For` loop repeats until a specified condition evaluates to false. Arrays operations are one thing that can be used within this `for` loop body but not necessarily the only thing whereas `forEach` works only with Array.

**For loop structure:**

```js
for ([initialExpression]; [conditionExpression]; [incrementExpression]) {
 /* statement */
}
```

`For` loop is slightly better than `forEach` in performance but it is advised to use `forEach` whenever it can for more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

From: Eric Sarrion's Book “JavaScript from
Frontend to Backend.” :

**The difference between the for() loop and the forEach() method**

To show the difference between these two approaches (the **for()** **loop** and
**forEach() method**), let’s introduce a new element in the
array, at index 10, knowing that the last index used during the creation of the array was 4.
We thus create a new element that is much further away than the current last element of
the array. How will the array react to this enlargement?

```
// original array
var tab = ["Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", 
"Element 5"];

// adding a new element in the array, at index 10
tab[10] = "Element 9";
console.log("tab =", tab);

// display the array with a for() loop
console.log("Access to each element by a for() loop");
for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) console.log("tab[" + i + "]=", tab[i]);

// display the array by the forEach() method
console.log("Access to each element by the forEach() method");
tab.forEach(function(elem, i) {
 console.log("tab[" + i + "]=", elem);
});
```

We add an element to the array using tab[10] = "Element 9", then display the
contents of the array using the **for() loop** and then the **forEach() method**.
The result is displayed in the following figure:

[image]

The display of the **for() loop** shows that the elements with indices 5 to 9 exist but are of
value undefined, because effectively, no values have been inserted for these indices of
the array. However, the indices 5 to 9 with their undefined values are displayed by the
**for() loop**.

Conversely, the **forEach() method** provides the callback function indicated in
parameters with only the array elements that have actually been affected in the array.
This therefore avoids the elements at indices 5 to 9, which have not been assigned in
the program.