# VB.NET: error BC30389: 'i' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compilation

I maintain an ASP.NET/VB.NET website that targets .NET 3.5. I used to build with no issues. all of the sudden I start getting building errors:

error BC30389: 'i' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'

for every single-letter for loop control variable. for example:

```
For i = 0 To oDataTable.Columns.Count - 1
strHtml += "<td style='border : 1px solid black; font-size :13pt;'>" +         oDataTable.Columns(i).ColumnName + "</td>"
Next
```

If I change the var name from 'i' to 'ii' it goes away but that's not an option because we use for loop control vars like that in a million places in this site. I have never seen this type of errors before.

Here are my compiler settings:

```
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
<providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
<providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
<providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
```

The only thing new on my work station is that I installed .NET 4.5.2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a Friend variable exists with the name `i` that is conflicting with your loop variables.  If you right click and choose _Go to definition_ maybe you can find the friend variable.

Comment: Did you Dim your variable first? If not, I would suggest you turn Option Strict On

Answer (score 0):

I think For Each is the better approch to loop through a collection which size is unknown. so you can loop through the `Datacolumns` using [`For Each`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929586/what-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach) as this

```
    Dim strHtml As new  StringBuilder()
    For Each dc As DataColumn In oDataTable.Columns
        strHtml.Append("<td style='border : 1px solid black; font-size :13pt;'>" + dc.ColumnName + "</td>")
    Next
```

And here i suggest you to use `StringBuilder` instead for string. since it consumes less amount of memory.