# For Loop vs Foreach Loop

Tags: c#

Can anyone please let me know What is difference between "For loop" OR "Foreach loop" & which is faster from both of them?

I searched on internet but can't find any detailed answer with example. :-/

**The only difference I found is :-**

- For :- should be used when wants to iterate for a fixed number of times.
- Foreach :- should be used when wants to iterate through collection.

Please help me out here.

Any help is appreciated. :-)

*Thanks.*

Comment: for loop can be used to add or remove items and it can iterate in reverse order. foreach is more like for loop everything.

Comment: You can't add, delete, change item in `foreach` loop, that's one of the important differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is a construct that says "perform this operation n.times".

Example -

```
int n = 5; // You can assign any preferred value  
          for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
             (your operation); // it will be in 5 times
          }
```

The foreach loop is a construct that says "perform this operation against each value/object in this IEnumerable"

Example -

```
List<string> names= new List<string>();

        names.Add("Tom");
        names.Add("Denver");
        names.Add("Nash");
        names.Add("Cheruu");
        names.Add("Amy");

        foreach(string name in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

You can find more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929586/what-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach/39331851#39331851).

Comment: Thank you so much for  your answer @Thilli77. It helped me. :-)