# Reverse Order Of Object[] Param

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach

I am using this syntax in my `foreach` loop and it loops through as it should, but is there a way to have the loop start at the last index instead of the first?

This is the syntax I am using to start at the first element, but could it be altered so that it starts reverse?

```
foreach (BD bData in bl.NameList)
{
Object[] param = new Object[2];
param[0] = bData.m_Width;
param[1] = bData.m_Height;
DataGrid1.Rows.Insert(0, param);
}
```

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want to iterate through it backwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what data type `BD` is, but I have to assume it is an indexable list (i.e. it has a `this[int]` property, and either a `Count`, `GetUpperBound()`, or `Length` property). Otherwise the question "can I do it in reverse order?" is a meaningless question, because you would be working with a list with indeterminate order which would also have an indeterminate reverse order.

So, given that it is indexable, you simply need to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`.

```
for (int i = bd.NameList.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    var bData = bd.NameList[i];
    Object[] param = new Object[2];
    param[0] = bData.m_Width;
    param[1] = bData.m_Height;
    DataGrid1.Rows.Insert(0, param);
}
```

Or... if you love the enumerator... just use `Add(X)` instead of `Insert(0, X)`, which will append to the end of the list. Obviously this will only work if you are adding to a `DataGridViewRowCollection` and may not work in other situations.

```
foreach (BD bData in bl.NameList)
{
    Object[] param = new Object[2];
    param[0] = bData.m_Width;
    param[1] = bData.m_Height;
    DataGrid1.Rows.Add(param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reverse the list before putting it through `foreach`, but that is not as efficient as simply using a `for` loop and iterating through it backwards, as described here: [Possible to iterate backwards through a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211608/possible-to-iterate-backwards-through-a-foreach)