# How to Split a object list into sublists grouping by elements(dateTime and String) C#

Tags: c#, linq, sublist, tobjectlist

Im tring to make sub-list based on main list with 9 records according to datetime ascending order & then pcName(string).

my sorted sublist need to be like below

**ObjectList 1 :**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**150**,**Test1**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**200**,**Test1**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**250**,**Test1**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**300**,**Test1**

**ObjectList 2 :**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**350**,**Test2**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**400**,**Test2**

**ObjectList 3 :**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**450**,**Test1**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**500**,**Test1**

**ObjectList 4 :**

2615,2019-11-22 16:03:22.**550**,**Test3**

This object list need to take according to sequence ObjectList[0] ,ObjectList[1] ,ObjectList[2]  and ObjectList[3]

I mentioned below my sample code

But this only provides me 3 sublist sets(Item1) filter based with **Test1, Test2 & Test3** and 9 sublists but i want as above 4 sub lists. where i want to change code ?? **Please help me**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Identity> listOfIdentity = new List<Identity>()
            {
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.550"),PcName="Test3"},                              
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.300"), PcName="Test1"},                            
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.350"), PcName="Test2"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.400"), PcName="Test2"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.200"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.500"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.250"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.450"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.150"), PcName="Test1"}              
            };
            List<Identity> sortedIdentity = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).ToList(); // here i order by time and then pc name

            var items1 = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).GroupBy(x => x.PcName).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList(); //sub list create based with **Test1, Test2 & Test3** (3 sub lists)
            var items2 = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).GroupBy(x => new { x.QCTime, x.PcName }).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList(); //sub list create based with each time and pc name (9 sublists)
        }

        class Identity
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public DateTime QCTime { get; set; }
            public string PcName { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: what is the criteria that separates ObjectList1 and ObjectList3?

Comment: Mainly different time,
It need to take as two objects list due to base QCTime and another PC(Test2) name in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using `Linq.Aggregate`:

```cs
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Identity> listOfIdentity = new List<Identity>()
    {
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.550"), PcName="Test3"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.300"), PcName="Test1"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.350"), PcName="Test2"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.400"), PcName="Test2"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.200"), PcName="Test1"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.500"), PcName="Test1"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.250"), PcName="Test1"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.450"), PcName="Test1"},
        new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.150"), PcName="Test1"}
    };
    List<Identity> sortedIdentity = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).ToList(); // here i order by time and then pc name
    var result = sortedIdentity.Skip(1).Aggregate(new List<List<Identity>> { new List<Identity> { sortedIdentity[0] } }, (lists, curr) =>
    {
        if (curr.PcName == lists.Last()[0].PcName)
            lists.Last().Add(curr);
        else
            lists.Add(new List<Identity> { curr });
        return lists;
    });
}
```

It iterates over each element and checks, if it's *PcName* is the same as previous. If it is, it goes on the same list, else new list is created with this element.

---

EDIT: More elegant solution suggested by [Matt.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9534819/matt-g)

```cs
    List<Identity> sortedIdentity = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).ToList();
    var result = sortedIdentity.Aggregate(new List<List<Identity>>(), (lists, curr) => 
   { 
        if (curr.PcName == lists.LastOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault()?.PcName)
            lists.Last().Add(curr);
        else
            lists.Add(new List<Identity> { curr });
        return lists;
    });
```

Comment: +1. I would avoid the skip using `var result = sortedIdentity.Aggregate(new List<List<Identity>>(), (lists, curr) =>
    {
        if (curr.PcName == lists.LastOrDefault()?.FirstOrDefault()?.PcName)`

Comment: @Matt.G your solution looks cleaner, thanks. I've added it to the answer

Comment: thank you very much, both answers working perfect for my scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in LINQ method specialized at grouping consecutive elements in one pass. Creating one is not that difficult though. An implementation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146898/split-an-ienumerable-into-multiple-ienumerables/58149232#58149232), having the signature bellow:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> SplitByPredicate<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, bool> splitPredicate);
```

You could use it to solve your problem like this:

```
var sublists = listOfIdentity
    .OrderBy(x => x.QCTime)
    .ThenBy(x => x.PcName)
    .SplitByPredicate((x, y) => x.PcName != y.PcName);
```

A different implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576497/c-how-to-iterate-over-a-list-with-many-conditions-filters-and-groups-of-items/58577012#58577012), having the slightly different signature bellow:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<TSource>> GroupConsecutiveByKey<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector);
```

...that could be used like this:

```
var sublists = listOfIdentity
    .OrderBy(x => x.QCTime)
    .ThenBy(x => x.PcName)
    .GroupConsecutiveByKey(x => x.PcName);
```

Answer (score -1):

since you are trying to group by DateTime column and which only varies in MilliSeconds, grouping is not done as per your expectation. I modified your code as below:

```
class Identity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime QCTime { get; set; }
        public string PcName { get; set; }

        public string QCTimeForGroup
        {
            get
            {
                if (QCTime.Millisecond <= 300)
                {
                    return "SL1";
                }
                else if (QCTime.Millisecond > 300 && QCTime.Millisecond <= 400)
                {
                    return "SL2";
                }
                else if (QCTime.Millisecond > 400 && QCTime.Millisecond <= 500)
                {
                    return "SL3";
                }

                return "SL4";
            }
        }
    }


private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Identity> listOfIdentity = new List<Identity>()
            {
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.550"),PcName="Test3"},                              
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.300"), PcName="Test1"},                            
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.350"), PcName="Test2"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.400"), PcName="Test2"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.200"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.500"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.250"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.450"), PcName="Test1"},
               new Identity() {id= 2615,QCTime=DateTime.Parse("2019-11-22 16:03:22.150"), PcName="Test1"}              
            };
            List<Identity> sortedIdentity = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).ToList(); // here i order by time and then pc name

            var items1 = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).GroupBy(x => x.PcName).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList(); //sub list create based with **Test1, Test2 & Test3** (3 sub lists)
            var items2 = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName).GroupBy(x => new { x.QCTime, x.PcName }).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList(); //sub list create based with each time and pc name (9 sublists)
            var items3 = listOfIdentity.OrderBy(x => x.QCTime).ThenBy(x => x.PcName)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.QCTimeForGroup, x.PcName }).Select(grp 
                        => grp.ToList()).ToList(); 
        }
```